# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2' has no attribute 'logging'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have updated to the latest `tensorflow` via `pip3`:

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

The following code is generating the error in the question title

```
tf.logging.info('embedding_name: %s', FLAGS.embedding_dimension)
```

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2' has no attribute 'logging'

Is this an out-of-date way to invoke the logging? Is there an alternative?

Comment: Try disabling `v2` behaviour - `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf; tf.disable_v2_behavior()`

Comment: Take a look at this - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26662

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tf.logging.info('embedding_name: %s', FLAGS.embedding_dimension)` is indeed an out-dated way of doing this. It is no longer supported. You can use `tf.get_logger` as an alternative. Here is an working example.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import logging

logger = tf.get_logger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger.info(' Hello World from TF')
```

outputs:

```
INFO:tensorflow: Hello World from TF
```

Comment: Is there any documentation for the logger object itself? TF's page for tf.get_logger() currently just states that it returns a TF Logger object, but there doesn't seem to be any info on what that object actually does.